# remove later strings starting with a certain thing in a list python

Tags: python, string, list, startswith

I have a list like this:

```
['a b d', 'a b e', 'c d j', 'w x y', 'w x z', 'w x k']
```

I want to remove all of the strings that occur after a string that starts with the same 4 characters as it. For example, `'a b e'` would be removed because `'a b d'` occurs before it.

The new list should look like this:

```
['a b d', 'c d j', 'w x y']
```

How can I do this?

(NOTE: The list is sorted, as per @Martijn Pieters' comment)

Comment: So what should happen to `['w x y', 'a b d', 'a b e', 'c d j', 'w x z', 'w x k']`, where `'w x '` is a prefix for elements that occur much later? Is the output expected to be `['w x y', 'a b d', 'c d j']` still?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - The list is sorted, so this should not matter

Comment: Where are the four characters?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: spaces included, the first string starts with `'a b '`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep, gotcha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a generator function to remember the starts:

```
def remove_starts(lst):
    seen = []
    for elem in lst:
        if elem.startswith(tuple(seen)):
            continue
        yield elem
        seen.append(elem[:4])
```

So the function skips anything that starts with one of the strings in `seen`, adding the first 4 characters of anything it does allow through to that set.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['a b d', 'a b e', 'c d j', 'w x y', 'w x z', 'w x k']
>>> def remove_starts(lst):
...     seen = []
...     for elem in lst:
...         if elem.startswith(tuple(seen)):
...             continue
...         yield elem
...         seen.append(elem[:4])
...
>>> list(remove_starts(lst))
['a b d', 'c d j', 'w x y']
```

If your input is sorted, this can be simplified to:

```
def remove_starts(lst):
    seen = ()
    for elem in lst:
        if elem.startswith(seen):
            continue
        yield elem
        seen = elem[:4]
```

This saves on prefix-testing by limiting to just the last one.

Comment: why are you using a set at all?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: hrm, you are right, there is no chance of duplicates. It has to be a mutable structure, but `str.startswith()` only takes a tuple (or a string).

Comment: Wouldn't a set actually be the best approach storing the first four chars in the set and only yielding if the four chars were not in the set?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I don't know; prefix testing is pretty fast, but the conversion from list to tuple takes a hit there each time. We could time it, but I'm out of time right now.

Comment: I suppose it also comes down to slice size, amount of strings and strings with unique prefixes. Signing off for the night too so it might be a job for another day

Answer (score 2):

You could also use an `OrderedDict`, the keys can be the first four chars where the values will be the first string that contains those four characters:

```
lst = ['a b d', 'a b e', 'c d j', 'w x y', 'w x z', 'w x k']

from collections import OrderedDict

print(list(OrderedDict((s[:4], s) for s in lst).values()))
['a b e', 'c d j', 'w x k']
```

Comment: @BhargavRao, you could have used that fancy spelling in an edit ;)

Comment: Lol, I will do that the next time :D